# How to texturize a circle mesh with a horizontal/vertical texture?

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, texture-coordinates, vector-mapping

I'm using this node scheme (screenshot below) to create a brushed steel in my object, but I need this brush show horizontally on my object.
As my object has a circle mesh, the texure is shown circled following the mesh.

How can I make this texture appear horizontally or vertically in my object?

My mesh is like this (screenshot below), and the Unwrap is like this (screenshot below).

[image]

This is a piece of my render result, showing the circled texture.

[image]

And this is how I need it to be.

[image]

How can I make this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to play with the Mapping Z rotation?

Comment: Yes, I have. I've already tried to play with all. Without success =(

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/eGMzQ4XW

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/345ddf531ea1405c91a6b9d3d13b4db8

Comment: actually I have an older 2.8 version so they are some things I don't get in your nodes, for example the Mapping seems to work as Anisotropic, if I replace them with my nodes it works fine...

Comment: Can you send me with your nodes please ? If it works fine is ok.

Comment: problem is I don't know what you exactly want, try to replace the Mapping with a new one, and don't use Anisotropic node

Comment: I need the brushed steel on material looks like this on link below, for me doesn't matter how. But I have tried to not use Anisotropic node as well. Without success. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18wy8ho6NRmd5toAUOd1YYzjuYJrosSAI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: no, DON'T use Anisotropic, just a basic Texture Coordinate > Mapping > Noise > ColorRamp, use it as a factor in a Mix Shader to separate two different nodes (for example 2 more or less rough Glossy), and play with the X or Y scale of the Mapping...